# Insert properties of DapperRow into database?

Tags: dapper

I have a DapperRow dynamic object containing fields retrieved from a table.  I had gotten the DapperRow from a previous Query.

I'd like to insert these fields, and a few others, into a different table.  However, I can't pass the dynamic in the Execute

```
con.Execute(insertStatment, rowData);
```

I will drop back to standard SQL and bind the parameters myself -- I'm just wondering if there's some Dapper feature I'm missing.

Thanks

Comment: Do you know ... I genuinely don't think it has *ever occurred to me* that somebody would want to do that. I guess one unfortunate consequence there is : if we make it work for `DapperRow`, people will want it to work for any `dynamic`, which gets very messy very quickly. So that I can understand the situation: is there a reason you can't use a defined type via `Query<T>` instead of the dynamic (non-generic `Query`) API?

Comment: "... reason you can't use a defined type?" - I can use a defined type - there just hasn't been a need for one.  In this app, most of this data is manipulated based on meta data - there are no defined types  I was able to pull the source row without a type and was just trying to see if I could populate the target without needing one, also.  But, there's no reason I can't create a type.  Thanks.  Dapper is delightful to use.

Comment: we can almost certainly make this work if we want it to - it just seems an unusual scenario :)

Comment: I'd guess it is out of the ordinary.  I asked just to make sure I wasn't overlooking something.  Thanks